# SFML с++ Помогите добавить иконку

Tags: c++, sfml

Нужна ваша помощь. 
Каким образом мне добавить иконку в sfml проект?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хех, вопрос закрыт. 
Кому будет интересно то как добавить иконку:

```
Image icon;
if (!icon.loadFromFile("images/icon.png"))
{
    return 1;
}
window.setIcon(32, 32, icon.getPixelsPtr());
```